# How to stream swf file in android WebView

Tags: android, listview, flash, webview, video-streaming

My app is supporting min api level 15 and I want to show a list which streams video from remote servers and video can be of any file format, thus I am considering the WebView as best choice but I am unable to stream swf file in WebView. And also for other files the WebView is showing jumping effect in ListView after loading the Videos.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us what have you already tried? Some code would be useful in order to understand what could be the problem.

Until then, you could try the following:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); 
} 
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
}

mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

mWebView.loadUrl("http://your_file_location.swf");
```

Comment: I am not getting any way to begin as 'mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true)' is deprecated. So, wouldn't be able to put any code.

Comment: I've updated my answer. According to the [WebSettings Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginState%28android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState%29) API levels beyond 18 will not support plugins and should not be used.

Comment: yup, our app is supporting the min sdk level as 15 but we are majorly focusing this feature for lollipop onwards devices i.e. from api level 21 onwards, thus stuck.